# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am making this app where users can see their own location and other users location. I recently just got an error saying

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

at this line:

```
var lat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
```

I have not managed to fix it.

**What is causing it and how can I fix it?**

For any who might would like the rest of the code:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var myLocation: [CLLocation] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var MapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PasswordTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var EmailTF: UITextField!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        let lat = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
        let lon = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        MapView!.setRegion(region, animated:  true)

        let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        anotation.coordinate = location
        anotation.title = "My tittle"
        anotation.subtitle = "My Subtitle"

        MapView!.addAnnotation(anotation)

        print("Welcome in MapViewController")
    }
}
```

Comment: The location manager should be a property, not a local variable.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Now the error moved down to let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)

Comment: The error is probably caused by force-unwrapping a nil optional using '!'. You should rewrite your code to avoid using '!' to force-unwrap optionals. Switch to optional binding to determine where the unexpected nil value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [@matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34799983/1664443) is talking about:

> The problem is that you are asking for the location manager's location
>   without checking to see whether the result is nil

Here's how you check to see if your value is nil:

**option 1:**

```
guard let lat = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude else {
    return
}
```

**option 2:**

```
if let latCheck = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude {
    // assign your lat value here
} else {
   // handle the problem
}
```

You need to change your mindset, when you see an `!` you should probably be unwrapping your optional value in one of the above two ways.

---

**update based on comments:**

You can also try creating a new variable to work with and see how it works:

```
guard let location = locationManager.location else {
    return
}
```

then:

```
let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
let lon = location.coordinate.longitude
```

Comment: It still wants me to force tunwrapping them with "!".

Comment: @TomJames updated with another possible solution, if this doesn't work I'll have to take a look when I get home

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are asking for the location manager's `location` without checking to see whether the result is `nil`. Well, it is (probably because there has not been time to get the actual location yet). Therefore, when you try to get that location's latitude and longitude, `lat` and `lon`, they are `nil` as well. Therefore when you force-unwrap them, you crash, because you cannot unwrap `nil`.

Comment: I am not sure how you do that? PLease see my update. Maybe you can see whats wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your time and help